# Put dynamic OSGi service selection in its own service?

Tags: java, osgi

In the design of our `OSGi` system we have a repeated scenario where one service wants to apply some specific handling ("treatment") to a sub-set of the deployed services. In the simple case we would let the targeted services have some service property assigned to indicate they want that special treatment, and then have the treatment services find them whiteboard style.

**But how is this best designed when the algorithm for deciding what services sub-set to target needs to be implemented with `Java` logic, and is not easily represented with a static property set by bundles themselves?**

Additionally, if we have multiple treatment services that want to reuse the same service targeting, ideally the selection algorithm should be implemented in its own service. Let's call it `SelectService`, and say that it has logic for dynamically identifying services of the "abc" and "xyz" categories.

I can think of these main alternatives to go about this, maybe there are more?

1. Let `SelectService` inspect deployed services and then somehow (how?) set properties "abc" and "xyz" on them when applicable. Then treatment services can use a standard `ServiceTracker` with a property filter to find the services they want.
2. Let `SelectService` offer methods `getAbcServices()` and `getXyzServices()` that return some `ServiceTracker`-like object. Treatment services can call these methods to find the targeted services.
3. Let treatment services declare something in the service registry (service interface or service property) to express an interest in service selections. `SelectService` then finds these wishes whiteboard style and notifies treatment services about selections.
4. This is the wrong way to think in an `OSGi` system and you shouldn't even want to do this :-)

---

EDIT 1:

To summarize the scenario you could say that it is similar to extension services like Declarative Services or Blueprint:

```
targeted  <-->  extender
service         service
```

with the addition that the extender service is split into two parts/layers for reuse of the selection logic:

```
targeted        extender         extender
service   <-->  service    <-->  service
                treatment   **   selection
                logic            logic
```

The interesting part is the API (**) between the treatment and selection logic as it mentions other services and also need some add/remove event mechanism. For understandability it is also desired to use as much of standard OSGi patterns and support functions as possible.

---

[Meta: It might be good to partition the discussion into one answer thread (answer+comments) per alternative?]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do "dynamic" or programmatic filtering of services, you need to use a static filter that takes in **all** services that may potentially be selected. The simplest such filter is the *null* filter, which simply takes in all services of the correct type.

For example to implement with Declarative Services:

```
@Reference(multiple = true, dynamic = true, optional = true)
public void addFooService(Foo foo, Map<String, Object> serviceProps) {
    // TODO: implement logic here to read serviceProps. Return early from
    // this method if the service doesn't match your dynamic criteria.
}
public void removeFooService(Foo foo, Map<String, Object> serviceProps) {
    // Be careful here, you will get services back that you didn't care about in the
    // 'add' method.
}
```

Now to address the second part of the question... making the selection logic itself into a service is an interesting idea, but it will make your life complicated. My main concern is: what should happen if the `SelectService` changes dynamically? I will have to re-filter the complete set of services based on the new selection algorithm. And what happens *before* the `SelectService` comes along... do I see all services unfiltered? Or zero services? etc

As to your final question about whether you are going down the right path... it's difficult to say without any idea about the real use-case. However I think that you're probably making things more complicated than they need to be. For example, maybe you shouldn't have such a large number of services of the same type? Maybe you should partition them into multiple types?

As an alternative to duplicating the selection logic in many clients, or pulling it into a Selection Service, why not create a single component that implements the selection logic, and then offer some higher-level or wrapping functionality based on the aggregated set?

Comment: The type of use-cases are inspecting things like annotations or xml declarations on potential services and apply some extension behaviour, like DS and BluePrint do but simpler. The targeted services don't share interfaces and are not consumed by the treatment services, they are just treated or extended in some way by them. As stated, I want to reuse the selection logic in several treatment services that look for the same "target category" and I do realize the same problems you state. I don't understand your last paragraph though, are you suggesting reuse through embedding?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at service proxying. With the OSGi service hooks you can selectively hide services and register a proxy. This model allows you to do almost anything while the consumers of those services remain oblivious of what's happening.

`soapbox {`
That said, in general, I would try to keep things simple. Though many of these "extensions" look incredibly useful by the author for some simple work they tend to become bottlenecks over time. Lack of extensive documentation and usually not having the needed functionality over time makes them PITAs for future developers.

I've seen so many systems that became very complex not because of their domain but because over time too many developers added their own middleware in an attempt to reduce their own workload, i.e. self-inflicted complexity. Sometimes a bit of redundancy is easier to understand/maintain.
`}`

Comment: I'm looking for how to refactor out the target service selection code out of the treatment/extender service and not for how to update the target service, if I understand correctly you replied to the latter? I updated my question to make this clearer. Agreed about self-inflicted complexity ;-) but we see a repeating pattern so are trying to see if we can make something reusable out of it.

Comment: Assume we have a number of "plain" services S1..Sn. We also have an AjaxService that can expose other services as JSON, and a CallLoggingService that log calls made on other services public interface. I have Java logic examining several combinations of annotations to decide which sub-set of S1..Sn to apply AjaxService and CallLoggingService to. I'd like to plug in more treatment/extender services that reuse the same selection logic. It would be nice to be able to replace the selection logic itself (if this becomes a service). The question is what the selection logic's API should look like?

Comment: Hmm, I think you're on the wrong track. An AjaxService should use the whiteboard pattern. It is trivial inspect a service in the bind method and see if you should track it. A CallLoggingService should use proxies (sure as hell happy I do not have to parse your logs!). Using DS they both are VERY straightforward to make and using Config Admin you set what services they see. They both sound very different. I think my best advice is to just implement things separately until you notice a lot of implementation redundancy ... only then fix it if it is worth the effort.

Comment: But the thing is that S1..Sn do not express any interface or property that say they should be handled by AjaxService. It is the pluggable logic in "SelectService" that decides whether this is a service of the "xyz" category, and then AjaxService asks SelectService for services in this category.

Comment: I'm not asking how to implement AjaxService or CallLoggingService, these are just examples of possible plugged in behaviour extensions. I'm asking how to make the service selection pluggable. So far I don't think you have touched on that?

Comment: What I am saying is that imho the examples have little in common. So the best way is to implement it optimal in each case, not trying to optimize ahead of time. Then when you have experience with 4/5 use cases you see implementation patterns appearing. Then encode those patterns. Again, I do not recognize your problem so maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: It all boils down to that SelectService has a list of other services that it wants to give to treatment services such as AjaxService. Which of the alternatives 1, 2 or 3 in the original question is most suitable for handing over this (live) service list?

Comment: I think 4 is by far the best solution because from my ( admittedly) limited understanding you try to reinvent, or layer over, existing functionality. Since the concrete use cases you gave seem to have good solutions in e.g. DS I fail to say the need for something new.